# Capistrano using wrong ruby version after rvm update

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, capistrano, ruby-2.4

I have a capistrano 3.4.0 script that has successfully deployed an app for years.  However today I updated RVM and am trying to deploy my rails app which I'm upgrading to Rails 5.1.4.  Capistrano seems to work well for the first part but then throws this error...

```
cd /srv/www/my_app/releases/20180124210207 && ~/.rvm/bin/rvm default do bundle install --path /srv/www/my_app/shared/bundle --without development test --deployment --verbose
 DEBUG [14a8f315]   /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs'
 DEBUG [14a8f315]   : 
 DEBUG [14a8f315]   Could not find bundler (>= 0) amongst [bundler-unload-1.0.2, did_you_mean-1.1.0, executable-hooks-1.3.2, gem-wrappers-1.3.2, minitest-5.10.1, net-telnet-0.1.1, passenger-5.1.12, power_assert-0.4.1, rack-2.0.3, rake-12.0.0, rubygems-bundler-1.4.4, rvm-1.11.3.9, test-unit-3.2.3, xmlrpc-0.2.1]
 DEBUG [14a8f315]    (
 DEBUG [14a8f315]   Gem::LoadError
 DEBUG [14a8f315]   )
```

Obviously I don't want to use ruby 1.9.1, when I ssh into the linux both and do a ruby -v it says Ruby 2.4.1.  I set that as the default by using

```
rvm get stable
rvm install ruby 2.4.1
sudo rvm --default use 2.4.1
```

I'm also using the capistrano-rvm gem, when the capistrano script begins the deployment it says

```
 DEBUG [081254bd] Command: ~/.rvm/bin/rvm current
 DEBUG [081254bd]   ruby-2.4.1
 DEBUG [081254bd] Finished in 2.704 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).

 DEBUG [e45e0d6b] Command: ~/.rvm/bin/rvm version
 DEBUG [e45e0d6b]   rvm 1.29.3 (latest) by Michal Papis, Piotr Kuczynski, Wayne E. Seguin [https://rvm.io]
```

Why is it switching to ruby 1.9.1 mid way through the deployment?  How do I get it to use my default ruby version of 2.4.1?

Comment: Do you have a `.ruby-version` file in your app? or A ruby line at the top of your Gemfile?

Comment: No.  In my gemfile I do have gem 'rails', '5.1.4'.

Comment: Darn... just thought it could have been a mismatch of that kind. I've occasionally had an old `.ruby-version` hanging around that I forgot about...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to do the following to get it working...

```
sudo chown -R your_user /home/deployer/.rvm
gem install bundler
```

Then run capistrano script.